# Image Parameters (Standard Deviation, Mean and Entropy) of an RGB Image with pixel randomness/irregularities

Tags: image, rgb, pixel, entropy

I have stumbled upon some good explanations on how to get the entropy of an RGB image using matlab. Matlab provides a built in function that allows as to get the entropy of a grayscale image using  -sum(p.*log2(p)). One answer provides a way on how to get the entropy of an rgb image given in this link  --->  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28239789/3995148

How Matlab explains the function :

> E = entropy(I) returns E, a scalar value representing the entropy of grayscale image I. Entropy is a statistical measure of randomness that can be used to characterize the texture of the input image.
>
> Entropy is defined as -sum(p.*log2(p))
>
> where p contains the histogram counts returned from imhist. By default, entropy uses two bins for logical arrays and 256 bins for uint8, uint16, or double arrays.
>
> I can be a multidimensional image. If I has more than two dimensions, the entropy function treats it as a multidimensional grayscale image and not as an RGB image.

Questions :

Does entropy consider or detects image irregularities? For example, if variable A contains the entropy of IMAGE AA, and variable B contains the entropy of the Alter(IMAGE AA). Where Alter is a function that swaps random pixels inside the image. Does Variable A and Variable B contains the entropy value? Given that both images contains the same pixels but differs only on their position in the image. I need to clarify because I am new to this topic,

Does entropy need to consider image irregularities, why?
What entropy implementation do I need to cover image irregularities?
Is it available as built in function in python or other image processing programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by *"irregularity"*, but I can show entropy does not vary when you rotate an image, flip it horizontally or vertically, using ImageMagick, so therefore it does not matter if you exchange pixels:

```
# Check entropy of image
convert image.png -print '%[entropy]' null:
0.89247

# Rotate 90 degrees and check - still same
convert image.png -rotate 90 -print '%[entropy]' null:
0.89247

# Rotate 270 degrees and check - still same
convert image.png -rotate 270 -print '%[entropy]' null:
0.89247

# Flip image and check - still same
convert image.png -flip -print '%[entropy]' null:
0.89247

# Flop image and check - still same
convert image.png -flop -print '%[entropy]' null:
0.89247
```

You can check the standard deviation, mean and entropy all in one go with:

```
 convert image.png -rotate 90 -verbose +identify null: | grep -Ei "entropy|deviation|mean" | tail -3
  image.png=> PNG 70x46=>46x70 46x70+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.000
  mean: 105.147 (0.412341)
  standard deviation: 59.4199 (0.233019)
  entropy: 0.89247
```

Comment: Thank you for this I was bothered by someone telling me about this. Can i ask how did you the entropy of a colored image ?

Comment: The per-channel entropy is calculated for R, G and B and then they are averaged.

Comment: Can I use Shannons entropy per channel then do the average? I am planning to use python to get the entropy. Can you suggest a good way to program the getting of entropy of a colored image?

Comment: I'm sorry, you are nudging the limits of my knowledge. Maybe Eric will have some ideas - @emcconville

Comment: Or maybe @YvesDaoust might have a moment.

Answer (score 0):

the default function is there in the `matlab` for calculating the entropy.

Just try

```
I=imread('image name');
entropy(I)
```